# react-select v2 reorder on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, drag-and-drop, react-select

I'm using react-select v2 plugin for my select box and as I have multiple selections possibility enabled. I need to use drag and drop to switch order of the selected values.
Have you ever create feature like this, any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to improve the rendered options with drag&drop feature.

You can check the excellent [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/) library for that. They propose some React higher-order components that are easy to use if you are already familiar with common React patterns.